# Custom Translator training is failing

Tags: azure

I have tried to train a model several times and each time I get "Training failed". I have more than 17k sentences for training and almost 3k sentences for tuning. There is no log, error message, or any other information except "training failed". Please advice.

Comment: what exactly are you talking about? Cognitive services? ML studio?

Comment: For us to be able to help you out I think it's helpful if you let us know what software you are using (so we know to place the error message). Also more details about your sentences would help (language, sentence length etc). Help us help you?

Comment: Ms Azure - Cognitive Services - Custom Translator. I´m trying to train an EN>ES model. As for the sentences, I've used all I have in my TM, which ranges from short sentences (only a few words) to longer (more than 10 word sentences).